# skos:related vs skos:relatedMatch

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, graphdb, linked-data, skos

Can someone explain to me the difference between skos:related and skos:relatedMatch predicates?  My current understanding is that skos:related applies to concepts that are related "within" a scheme, whereas skos:relatedMatch is to concepts across different schemes. I am not sure if that is correct. Could someone please confirm if this is right? Or, if you think there is a better explanation, please help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the definition of [`skos:relatedMatch`](https://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.html#relatedMatch) ‒ it has two super-properties, `skos:related` and `skos:mappingRelation`. This means that `_:a skos:relatedMatch _:b` actually implies both `_:a skos:related _:b` and `_:a skos:mappingRelation _:b`.

Based on this, it can be concluded that `skos:related` must apply to *any* two concepts that are related in some way, not just within a concept scheme. This is supported by the [SKOS reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#L4160):

> However, note that using the SKOS semantic relation properties (`skos:broader`, `skos:narrower`, `skos:related`) to link concepts in **different** concept schemes is also **consistent** with the SKOS data model

Therefore feel free to use `skos:related` in any general case when you don't particularly care about mapping between two concept schemes.

Intriguingly enough, it is also possible to use `skos:relatedMatch` between concepts that are in the *same* scheme, per the reference:

> Note also that, because different people might re-organize concepts into concept schemes in different ways, a graph might assert **mapping** links between concepts in the **same** concept scheme, and there are **no** formal integrity conditions in the SKOS data model that would make such a graph inconsistent

In the end, this means that mapping relations are for convenience, to give you the idea that the two concepts are not necessarily part of the same hierarchy, or, more precisely, that there should be two distinct concept schemes, each containing one of them. But if you actually want to assert this fact (or the opposite), use `skos:inScheme`.

Answer (score 1):

it's right *skos:related* is used  between concepts within the same schema.
but can be interpreted as the addition of one concept to another (it's like *seeAlso*) or as a complete correspondence of related concepts (it's like *sameAs*). and the same is right for *skos:relatedMatch* but related concepts as you mentioned are in different schemas